# Axis2 problems with Inheritence

Tags: wsdl, apache-axis

We have object inheritance in our java classes and in the operations we are returning the base classes. Upon running Java2WSDL we noticed that only the base class object is created in the WSDL and the derived classes are completely ignored. There was no straight-forward way to handle this so we used the "extra classes" option in Java2WSDL and got the classes going. So now the WSDL looks complete.

When the client uses the WSDL (generated above) it is able to get the derived classes but when it passes them the service the service doesn't instantiate the corresponding derived class but instance always instantiates the base class, though the soap message contains the reference to the derived class. What I notice from here is it looks like the service is missing those bindings.

How do I fix this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am obviously not a Pro with Axis, but what you try to achieve looks quite like this item in the docs:

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/adb/adb-advanced.html#typeSupport

Also, you should state what serialization framework you use for your question to be complete.